# Ext JS Encoded base64 image set as background url

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, extjs, encode

Ext js and cordova plugin to use this code

**console.log(getBgPicture);**

Encoded images getting properly.

```
 setBodyStyle('background:url("'+'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+getBgPicture +'") no-repeat center; background-size: cover');
```

while executing will get this error

**app.js:1 GET data:image/jpeg net::ERR_INVALID_URL**

i have tried so many ways. If any one know please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should give arguments to `setBodyStyle` as object with `camelCase` parameters.

```
this.setBodyStyle({
    backgroundImage: "url('data:image/jpeg;base64," + getBgPicture + "')",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundPosition: "center"
});
```